# two fragments of ViewPager running parallel

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-tabs, fragmentpageradapter

I'm using viewpager with TabLayout. 
For example there are three Tabs: A,B,C.

In Each fragment I have AsyncTask.

When I'm moving to fragment A, the B fragment running too.
And when I moving to fragment B it is not refreshing. Its shows the result which was received when the fragment A was active. And parallel with it the fragment C running.

Can you please help me to fix this.

Thanks,
Petros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the result of  information that I read about this article , I understand that this is not possible. This is the future of viewpager.